# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, io, streamwriter

I am using the next code to log errors of an web application.

```
using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(sLogFilePath, true))
{                
myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -45}{1, -25}{2, -10 {3}", guid, DateTime.Now, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));      

}
```

Sometimes, the following exception 'System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '.txt' because it is being used by another process.' is thrown.

I think this is caused by multiple instances of the web app at the same time. Can you help me fix this problem, please ?

EDIT: I have to add that for every method I log like this:

Date - Method X started.

Date - Exception.Message (table not found or other errors)

Date - Method X stopped.

and when this Error appears, it's logged only this:

Date - System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've added this code to my class:

```
 public static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;

            try
            {
                stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch
            {
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

and now my LogToFile method is like this:

```
while (IsFileLocked(fi))
            {
            }

            using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(sLogFilePath, true))
            {
                if (displayTime == true)
                    myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -45}{1, -25}{2, -10}{3}", guid, DateTime.Now, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));
                else
                    myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -70}{1, -10}{2} ", guid, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));                
            }
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: It may improve the situation, but it has not solved it completely. The reason for this is that another process may have opened the file between the call to IsFileLocked and the creation of your StreamWriter.

Comment: Another issue you may get is that under very high load one thread could block out another thread. This is because there is no queue to ensure that waiting thread eventually get a look in. A thread can release a lock on the file and require it between another thread's checks. Also because this is polling the file with little pause between each attempt a waiting thread will likely use a high amount of CPU.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly Windows does not allow waiting on a file lock. In order to get around this all your applications will have to create a lock that all the processes involved can check.

The use of this code will only prevent threads within a single process from accessing the file:

```
/* Suitable for a single process but fails with multiple processes */
private static object lockObj = new Object();
lock (lockObj)
{
    using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(sLogFilePath, true))
    {                
        myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -45}{1, -25}{2, -10 {3}", guid, DateTime.Now, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));      
    }
}
```

In order to lock across multiple processes a Mutex lock is required. This gives a name to the lock that other processes can check for. It works like this:

```
/* Suitable for multiple processes on the same machine but fails for
   multiple processes on multiple machines */
using (Mutex myMutex = new Mutex(true, "Some name that is unlikly to clash with other mutextes", bool))
{
    myMutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(sLogFilePath, true))
        {
            myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -45}{1, -25}{2, -10 {3}", guid, DateTime.Now, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

}

I don't think Mutexes can be access from remote machines so if you have a file on a file share and you are trying to write to it from processes on multiple machines then you are probably better off writing a server component on the machine that hosts the file to mediate between the processes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need each thread to *eventually* write to the log, you could [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) the critical section

```
private static object fileLock = new Object();
...
lock (fileLock)
{
    using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(sLogFilePath, true))
    {                
        myStream.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -45}{1, -25}{2, -10 {3}", guid, DateTime.Now, StringEnum.GetStringValue(enumMsg), sText));      

    }
}
```

This means only 1 thread at any given time can be writing to the file, other threads are blocked until the current thread has exited the critical section (at which point the file lock will have been removed).

One thing to note here is that `lock` works *per process*, therefore if your site is running the context of a web farm/garden then you would need to look at a *system*-wide locking mechanism i.e. [Mutexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Trouble with this is that web server tend to run sites in multiple processes as well as multiple threads. The lock given here will only work for one process.

Comment: @MartinBrown "*web server tend to run sites in multiple processes*" - only if being run in the context of a web farm/garden. It's a valid point but given the OP hasn't mentioned anything about running as such I presume they aren't.

Comment: They do it when recycling processes as well. There is an overlap between the old and new process while the old process finishes off requests that started before the recycle started.

Comment: @MartinBrown hmm that's true, didn't think about it from that perspective. At that point, it comes down to probability - what are the chances of 1 thread locking the file *before* a recycle and another thread writing to the file *after* the recycle (whilst still being locked in the old process) - it would most likely never happen....but still could. I think in a single web server environment a Mutex is really just bolts & braces given the chance of a process overlap ever happening.

Answer (score 3):

Your web server will run requests in multiple threads. If two or more requests have to log exceptions at the same time, this will lead to the exception you see.

You could either lock the section as James proposed, or you could use a logging framework that will handle multithreading issues for you, for example [Lgo4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: The web server will probably run the site in multiple processes as well as multiple threads. Either permanently in the case of a web garden, or for a short period of time while recycling processes.