# Windows Service Filestream giving System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file "filename" because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've got a windows service that I have to modify. Current code is this:

```
 public IRecord2 GetRecord(string name)
 {
      string path = Path.Combine(this.DirectoryPath, name);
      if (!File.Exists(path))
          return null;
      byte[] contents;
      lock (locker)   {
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, bufferSize:4096, useAsync:true)) //WHERE THE PROBLEM IS OCCURRING
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    contents = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                    br.Close(); //unnecessary but threw it in just to be sure
                    fs.Close(); //unnecessary but threw it in just to be sure
                }
            }
            
        }
     return new Record2()
        {
            Name = name,
            Contents = contents
        };
}
```

Code that calls the function:

```
 public void Process(string pickupFileName)
    {
        string uniqueId = DateTime.Now.ToString("(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)");
        string exportFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pickupFileName) + "_" + uniqueId + ".csv";
        string archiveFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pickupFileName) + "_" + uniqueId + Path.GetExtension(pickupFileName);
        string unprocessedFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pickupFileName) + "_" + uniqueId + Path.GetExtension(pickupFileName);

        try
        {
            _logger.LogInfo(String.Format("Processing lockbox file '{0}'", pickupFileName));

            IRecord2 record = _pickup.GetRecord(pickupFileName);
            if (record == null)
                return;

            _archive.AddOrUpdate(new Record2() { Name = archiveFileName, Contents = record.Contents });

            string pickupFileContents = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(record.Contents);

            IBai2Document document = Bai2Document.CreateFromString(pickupFileContents);
            StringBuilder sb = Export(document);

            _export.AddOrUpdate(new Record2() { Name = exportFileName, Contents = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()) });

            _pickup.Delete(pickupFileName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Function that calls Process:

```
public void Process()
    {
        foreach (ConfigFolderPath configFolderPath in _configSettings.ConfigFolderPaths)
        {
            IRecordRepository pickup = new FileRepository(configFolderPath.PickupFolderPath);
            IRecordRepository export = new FileRepository(configFolderPath.ExportFolderPath);
            IRecordRepository archive = new FileRepository(configFolderPath.ArchiveFolderPath);
            IRecordRepository unprocessed = new FileRepository(configFolderPath.UnprocessedFolderPath);

            Converter converter = new Converter(Logger,pickup, export, archive, unprocessed);
            
            foreach (string fileName in pickup.GetNames())
            {
                if (_configSettings.SupportedFileExtensions.Count > 0 && !_configSettings.SupportedFileExtensions.Any(extension => extension.ToLower() == Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower()))
                    continue;

                Action action = () => converter.Process(fileName);
                _queue.TryEnqueue(action, new WorkTicket() { Description = String.Format("Processing '{0}'", fileName), SequentialExecutionGroup = fileName });
            }
        }
    }
```

When 1 file is sent to the service, it processes and reads the file correctly. However, if two files are sent (difference of 3 minutes), the first file will process correctly, but the second will give me "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file "filename" because it is being used by another process.

Is the solution to use a mutex as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29941548/4263285 or is there a better solution to solve this?

Edit: More context:

Service is constantly running - as soon as files are dropped into a folder, it begins the process.

1. get the file data (function up above)
2. take the data, transform it, and put it into a different file
3. Delete the original file from the one up above

rinse and repeat if more files

if one file is placed in the folder, it works correctly.
if two files are placed in the folder, it breaks on the second file
if service is stopped and restarted, it works again

Comment: "When ` file is sent to the service" I don't know what this means. How are you "sending" things to the service exactly? How are they both being processed? Do you have a loop, or is something responding to events? Need a little more context.

Comment: Added more context, thanks

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the code you have shared. Where is the code that iterates over the files that are found? Is there a loop? Where is the code that writes to the transformed file? Are both source files rewritten into the same destination file? When do you delete the original file? What specific line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Added additional context. 

specific line is 
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))

Answer (score 0):

In your code add ".Close()" here, at the end of the line :

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, bufferSize:4096, useAsync:true).Close())
```

Comment: This does not work "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.IO.FileStream"